# I have a HTTP 302 error when trying to navigate between pages

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, ajax, http

I have an application in web forms 2.0. I'm trying to navigate between pages and when I do that I receive "This page can't be displayed" error message in IE and Fiddler shows HTTP 302 which means the page has been moved temporarily even though I didn't change the location of this page. I copied the code of application in a different server and everything worked properly with no issues. I compared the 2 servers and I don't seen any difference in IIS settings between the 2 servers.

Should I make any changes in the code or in the server itself to handle redirecting pages?

Answer (score 0):

The [302 response status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) does not really mean that the ASPX page itself was moved (you didn't move it after all), but that after the browser requested that page at its URL, the page (or its server-side code) responded by "the real content you want to show is over there", maybe after some processing was done. In other words, the result of the redirect command you issued.

As to why you see an error, there is no data in your question to answer that. Are you sure the new URL is correct?

Comment: Kesting There's no old URL or new URL. It's been the same URL from the  beginning until now

Comment: You are "navigating between pages", I assume with a server side redirect. That redirect sends a 302 status and the location (url) to navigate to. It does not mean that pages were physically moved (which you didn't do, after all)